# can I develop webgl on google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, webgl

I saw google have web development IDE which looks fascinating for me.
But I cannot find how to develop webgl development, and there's just gs file stuff.
Do you know whether I could develop webgl on google app script?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot develop WebGL with Google scripting.

Google scripts are run on the server-side in Google cloud.

WebGL is a client-side Javascripting technology run in your web browser, not in Google servers.

To develop WebGL, create HTML and JS files on your local computer using your favorite programmer's text editor.